# Test a callback method's functionality in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a service as following.

```
InvService(...){
  this.getROItems = function(cb){
    $http.get('url').success(cb);  
  }  
}
```

One of the controllers which uses the above:

```
var roItems = [];  
InvService.getROItems(function(res){   
  roItems = res.lts.items;  
});
```

In Jasmine, I want to test that `roItems` are assigned the values from the response. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You may wish to consider changing the pattern to use promises instead of callbacks. like `this.getROItems = function() { return $http.get('url'); }` and `InvService.getROItems.then(function (res) { roItems = res.lts.items; })`. Using promises is pretty standard across AngularJS (which appears to be what you're using).

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that you have separated tests for you service and for your controller. If you want to test that `roItems` was assigned, you need to test your controller. Then, you could mock your service since it is not relevant for the controller test and make it return whatever you want. You need something like this:

```
describe('my awesome test', function() {

  it('my awesome test block',                           
       inject(function(InvService, $controller) {
              //This mocks your service with a fake implementation.
              //Note that I mocked before the controller initialization.
              spyOn(InvService, 'getROItems').and.callFake(function(cb){
                  var resultFake = {
                       lts: {
                           items: "whatever you want"
                       }
                  } 
                  cb(resultFake);
              });
              //This initializes your controller and it will use the mocked 
              //implementation of your service
              var myController = $controller("myControllerName");

              //Here we make the assertio
              expect(myController.roItems).toBe("whatever you want");
       }
  )
});
```

Comment: Just to add some flavor here: What @PedroVaz is doing here is "mocking" the service call when testing the controller. That makes it so that you are testing the unit of work, which is the controller's call to the service. Have a separate test that mocks `$http.get` and ensures that `getROItems` calls it correctly. You shouldn't need to test that `$http.get()` works; I think the AngularJS team already did that :).

Comment: Thanks for the addition @MikeMcCaughan :)

Comment: Sure, feel free to edit your answer and pop it in there :).

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan